# NameError: name 'restore_dbinstance_from_dbsnapshot' is not defined when using BOTO python module

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pycharm, boto, rds

I want to restore my RDS instances from the RDS snapshot to run on cloud using amazon Web services (AWS) , I am using Pycharm 3+ , The AWS CLI equivalent for this code using scripting language is : 
aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot

Python equivalent code is below:
import boto.rds
`restore_dbinstance_from_dbsnapshot('oracledev-final-snapshot','oracleid',db.m1.small,1521,'east-1')`

But when i run i get the above error mentioned in title.
can anyone help me on this please.
Advance thanks

Comment: Could you show the actual code that is causing the problem? Its hard to know what to suggest without some context.  The boto RDS module does have a ``restore_dbinstance_from_dbsnapshot`` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Pycharm, but I do it like this using ipython for CLI testing and LiClipse:

```
#import the module
import boto.rds
#connect to the region - you'll need your AWS info as the second two parameters if it isn't pre-configured
conn=boto.rds.get_all_connections("us-east-1")
#now is when you call the db creation, but from the connection
conn.restore_dbinstance_from_dbsnapshot('oracledev-final-snapshot','oracleid',db.m1.small,1521,'east-1')
```